# Java HashSet using customized class as key: "contains()" function always return false

Tags: java, key, equals, hashset, hashcode

I'm trying to use HashSet, while using my own class "Inner" as key type, as below:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
class Inner {
    int i;
    String s;
    public Inner(int i, String s) {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Inner inner = (Inner) o;
        return i == inner.i && s.equals(inner.s);
    }
}

public class testEquals {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        HashSet<Inner> hi = new HashSet<>();
        hi.add(new Inner(1,"abc"));
        System.out.println(hi.contains(new Inner(1,"abc")));
    }
}
```

It prints "false"

(1) My question is, as long as I try to use "contains" function, I have to construct a new object from "Inner" class to query, but because it's a new object, hashcode() is different. So I always get a "false" for "contains" functions.

(2) If I change the hashCode() to return "true" like equals when values are the same, then in other scenarios, different objects references are considered as "==" just like one unique reference.

(1) and (2) seems to conflict.

How to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override `hashCode` in a way that two equal objects will have the same `hashCode`.

For example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(i,s);
}
```

I'm not sure what's your problem with (2). If two objects are equal according to `equals()`, the `HashSet` should treat them as identical objects, even if they are not.

If, one the other hand, you wish the `HashSet` to treat any `Inner` instance as unique (regardless of the values of its instance variables), simply don't override `hashCode` and `equals`. However, it is rarely useful to use `HashSet` without overriding these methods.

Answer (score 4):

1. You have to overide `hashCode()` correctly without breaking the equals - hashcode contract.

> The contract between equals() and hashCode() is:
>
> 1. If two objects are equal, then they must have the same hash code.
> 2. If two objects have the same hash code, they may or may not be equal.

2. `hashCode()` does not returns true, it returns an int value. So just make sure it returns same int value for 2 different objects whose `equals()` return true.